# Are statements in the form bool = (boolean expression) Pythonic?

Tags: python

Take the following code

```
is_valid = command == "B"
```

or

```
can_move = move in legal_moves()
```

These are in the form

```
bool = (boolean expression)
```

I found myself writing statements like these and I'm wondering if it's considered "unpythonic" in some way. I'm not sure I like it very much, but it is concise.

So anyone have cleaner alternatives?

Comment: I'd use parenthesis to make it more clear like `is_valid = (command == "B")` or `can_move = (move in legal_moves())`, ternary operator would be nice too: `is_valid = True if (command == "B") else False`

Answer (score 5):

What you have, most people would consider just fine. It's clear, it's concise, it does exactly what it needs to do. The standard library also contains plenty of examples of it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems fine since

1. The standard libraries and documentation use this as well
2. I haven't found any PEP explicitly suggesting an alternative
3. [PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308) introduces conditional expressions of the form

   ```
   var = val1 if condition else val2
   ```

   which at least implicitly encourages inline boolean assignments. And

   ```
   bool = (boolean expression)
   ```

   is equivalent to, but more concise as

   ```
   bool = True if (boolean expression) else False
   ```

Comment: er, `True if (boolean expression) else False`, surely?

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Of course, if you test only once, you probably don't need to assign to a variable at all (except, of course, where you need to test before state changes).

Comment: It's for a function that returns a tuple containing several bools. I'd probably remove the function altogether, but it's a requirement for an assignment. I could put the expressions directly in the return statement over several lines, but that may be less readable.

Comment: It also serves to comment the code since the variable name explains what's going on to some degree. Also if some aggregate boolean expression is too long for a single line, you can break it up into boolean chunks stored in variables and finally do a `if right_room_for_an_argument and not been_told_once: no_you_havent()`.